# Memcache stats cachedump

Tags: memcached, telnet

We have found that with our memcache some keys tend to be lost. To debug, I am using the command `stats cachedump <slab> <limit>`

The output is something like this :

```
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-tmura [58 b; 1256946310 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-isuca [58 b; 1256946310 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-arpan [58 b; 1256946310 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-nanhai [59 b; 1256946252 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-naka3 [58 b; 1256946250 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-erlang [59 b; 1256946250 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-junkma [59 b; 1256946250 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-wilfue [59 b; 1256946250 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-quinte [59 b; 1256946250 s]
ITEM key-stuff-123-mlgtr-yanbe [58 b; 1256946250 s]
```

I get that `58 b` is the size; but what would be `1256946250 s`? The expiration in seconds? That seems kind of high (55 years)! So maybe our problem lies here... or maybe I misunderstood something.

Thanks!

Comment: "We have found that with our memcache some keys tend to be lost" I find that it's best to approach memcache with the assumption that this will happen.  It's a cache, not a datastore.  If you can't afford to lose keys, then use something more durable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the expiration time, as a unix timestamp.

So, item with '1256946250' will expire 'Sat Oct 31 01:44:10 2009'

Comment: Note also  [this SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418324/memcache-maximum-key-expiration-time) that highlights when setting values in memcache that any value less than 30 days is treated as *an offset to the current time* whereas a value greater than 30. days is actually treated as a timestamp. Of course, this doesn't affect the timestamp displayed by the cachedump command.

Answer (score 2):

Those are unix style timestamps.  You can go [here](http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php?action=stamp&stamp=1256946250&timezone=0) to convert them to a human readable date time.  Basically, it is the number of seconds since Jan 01 1970

Comment: or "date -d @1256946250" on a Linux system.