# How to interpret memcached cachedump?

Tags: memcached

I added an entry to memcached and looking at the cachedump.

```
set a 0 0 5
hello
STORED

stats cachedump 1 5
ITEM a [5 b; 1312548967 s]
END
```

The first value `5 b` is size of the item which is 5 bytes. The second one is what I'm confused about. It looks like time since epoch.

I tried adding another entry and even that entry got exactly same value.

```
set b 0 0 5
hello
STORED

stats cachedump 1 5
ITEM b [5 b; 1312548967 s]
ITEM a [5 b; 1312548967 s]
END
```

It looks like some kind of time, but I'm not sure what it really is. Can some one explain it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memcache stats cachedump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645764/memcache-stats-cachedump)

Answer (score 0):

This is meant for debugging purposes only and will [very likely be removed soon](http://groups.google.com/group/memcached/browse_frm/thread/d7e4fc23e45518a3).

You're invited to participate in that conversation.  Please let us know what you're interested in.