# Rails 3 cache not working. Dalli

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

development.rb cache configuration

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211',
    { :namespace => APP_NAME, :expires_in => 3.month, :compress => true }
```

production.rb cache configuration

```
   config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
   config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211',
     { :namespace => APP_NAME, :expires_in => 3.month, :compress => true }
```

in console

```
rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Rails.cache.write 'res', "Hello World"
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :002 >  Rails.cache.read 'res'
 => nil 
1.9.3-p125 :003 >
```

Why?

Comment: run **memcached -vv** and copy-paste the output here

Comment: this working if i replace 3.month to 0-30.day 90.day also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

memcached has a limit of 30 days if you defined the expiry that way - [Memcache maximum key expiration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418324/memcache-maximum-key-expiration-time)

Also see https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/55