# i want to set memcache expire 31day to use php code time()+3600*24*31,but it doesn`t work

Tags: php, memcached

```
<?php
$mem = new Memcache();
$flag = $mem -> connect('localhost',11211);

$mem -> set('color','red',0,30);//
$mem -> set('age',23,0,time()+30);//this code does not work because of "time()"
```

---

code time() which does not work

the result of my code run.

[image: the result of my code run]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memcache maximum key expiration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418324/memcache-maximum-key-expiration-time)

Comment: Any time higher than 30 days is interpreted as a unix timestamp date.

Comment: time()+30 is not higher than 30 days

Comment: As of 2017-10-02, we are 17,077 days past the unixtime epoch. 2,505,600 would be 29 days, time() returns a number greater than 1,506,942,580.

Answer (score 0):

Updated from Redis to Memcache,

> $mem -> set('color','red',0, 31 * 60 * 60 * 24);

Based on the documentation,

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to use memcache rather than redis,your code is code of redis